# Mean of selected values on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('values_per_hour.csv')
```

The dataframe is something like this:

```
Hour  Vel
0     10
1     11
2     15
.     .
.     .
.     .
23    7
0     17
1     3
2     4
.     .
.     .
.     .
23    2
0
...   ...
```

This dataframe has 10 years of data in hours. As can be seeable the first col is hours of days and the second col is velocity of something. The main objective is to take a mean of all velocities when the hour is 0. I just don't realize how to do that, would be helpful if someone could answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean indexing with `mean`:

```
df.loc[df['Hour'] == 0,'Vel'].mean()
```

or use `query`:

```
df.query('Hour == 0')['Vel'].mean()
```

If you would like to do every hour use:

```
df.groupby('Hour')['Vel'].mean()
```

Or try and make sure column is datetime dtype first:

```
df['Ano_Mes_Dia_Hora'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Ano_Mes_Dia_Hora) 

df.groupby(df['Ano_Mes_Dia_Hora'].dt.hour)['Vel'].mean()
```

Comment: For your first response did you mean to do `df[df['Hour'] == 0,'Vel'].mean()`? `df[df['Hour' == 0],'Vel'].mean()` will likely fail

Comment: @johnchase Yes, you are correct.  The trouble without test data to do a verification.  I wish more people would follow [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I don't explain very well my problem. In the way that @johnchase answered me I will need to do like 24 times this process to achieve 24 averages (one of each hour of a day).

My dataframe is like this:
         Ano_Mes_Dia_Hora  Vel
0 2007-01-01 12:00:00 AM 16.753743
1 2007-01-01 01:00:00 AM 18.060159
2 2007-01-01 02:00:00 AM 18.143939
...
23 2007-01-01 03:00:00 AM 18.212167

What I want is to know the average of each hour in the 10 years dataset..

Comment: @LeonardoFerreira  See the last statement using `groupby`.

Comment: @LeonardoFerreira as mentioned creating a small subset of the data and also an example of exactly what you would like the output to look like (rather than just a description) would likely lead to a more accurate answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: @johnchase Thanks so much! The last part of your comment work so well! Thanks Scott Boston for your attention too! I am sorry for the trouble in the question.